# Issue in wp:docPr while loading the docx file using docx4j

Tags: openxml, docx, docx4j

Processed a docx file which contains image using docx4j. After loading the file I logged document part, I found that **"title"** attribute is missing inside <wp:docPr> element. Let me know how to handle this. Thanks in advance

**Before Docx4j Process:**

```
<wp:docPr id="3" name="Picture 3" title="eps"/>
```

**After Docx**

```
<wp:docPr id="3" name="Picture 3"/>
```

Comment: How did you start with a title attribute?  It isn't part of the content model as far as I am aware:- http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/DrawingML/docPr.html

Comment: I come to know about title attribute via http://officeopenxml.com/drwPicInline.php.